# Swagger: is it possible to make an operation parameter constant / readonly?

Tags: swagger

This is the description of a certain parameter I have:

```json
{
    "name": "myParam",
    "description": "My param description",
    "required": true,
    "paramType": "query",
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue":"myValue"
}
```

The defaultValue is the only value the parameter can have, so is there a way to declare this? Seen in the context of the swagger-ui, I need the parameter's textbox to be read-only. I'm using swagger 1.2.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to define parameter that cannot be changed?

Answer (score 24):

The proper way to declare this would be:

```
{
    "name": "myParam",
    "description": "My param description",
    "required": true,
    "paramType": "query",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [ "myValue" ]
}
```

The "enum" property sets the possible values. Once you set a single value to it, that's the only one that could be used and that would be available in the UI for the user to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for replying! This works very well when the type is string, however, what happens in other cases, for example bool? I suppose I could declare it as a string with value "true" or "false", but it won't look very elegant if I generate a client library from it. Any ideas?

Comment: That depends on the Swagger specification version you use. In 1.2 and prior to that, "enum" was available only for string values.
In 2.0, "enum" is available for all primitives, so you can use it for booleans, numbers and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the game but with OpenAPI 3.1 you can do the following:

```yaml
defaultValue:
  type: string
  const:
   - myValue
```

Comment: I don't think you're too late. On contrary, you are too early, as OpenAPI 3.1 is [not supported by Swagger yet](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/1535) as of this writing.

Comment: This puts the value inside `[]`, as if it were an array.

Comment: Is there any library generator/tool that understands this format?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'pattern' of the string to avoid the enum - this could look better in Swagger:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "object": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "myParam"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "myParam": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "onlyAllowedValue$"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```