# How to return a default value in the response?

Tags: openapi

I have the following description:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: Optional multiline or single-line description in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/) or HTML.
  version: 0.1.9
servers:
  - url: http://localhost
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Internal staging server for testing
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':    # status code
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Now, when the user request `/ping` then it should receive `pong`. How to set default response payload to `pong`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a constant string in OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780038/how-to-define-constant-string-in-swagger-open-api-3-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to define it as an enum with a single value:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: Optional multiline or single-line description in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/) or HTML.
  version: 0.1.9
servers:
  - url: http://localhost
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Internal staging server for testing
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':    # status code
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                enum: [pong]
```

Answer (score 3):

Json Schema supports a `const` keyword with [version draft 6](https://json-schema.org/specification-links.html#draft-6), but [Open API was designed against draft 5](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/). Therefore, there is no support for `const` in open api schema spec.

As @Doqnach already suggested: Use a single valued `enum` and that is good solution, because (see https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html):

> It should be noted that const is merely syntactic sugar for an enum with a single element, therefore the following are equivalent:

```
{ "const": "United States of America" }

{ "enum": [ "United States of America" ] }
```

Similar questions:

- [How to define constant string in Swagger open api 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780038/how-to-define-constant-string-in-swagger-open-api-3-0)
- [Swagger: is it possible to make an operation parameter constant / readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039399/swagger-is-it-possible-to-make-an-operation-parameter-constant-readonly)

Comment: Is there a way to create an enum with a pre-defined key-value pair?

Comment: You mean a `default` for an enum field?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No - Let me clarify, as of now enum supports just a single value. Is it possible to define an object as a value for an enum in swagger open API 3.0?

Comment: I don't think so. An enum is a collection of strings. 

If you want do define a collection of constant object. You can define different object with constant members (single value enums).

And use `oneOf`.